# How long would it take a monkey to type out "ABBA" from 26 capital letters?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

What is the expected time it would take a monkey typing out random letters (the 26 capital letters) to type out "ABBA"?

I have this modelled as a Markov Process, but I have no idea how to actually find the E.T. I have 26^4 as a rough approximation but I know this isn't the exact answer.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_n$ for $0\leq n\leq 4$ be the expected number of additional keystrokes needed for the monkey to reach ABBA given that the last $n$ letters he has written corresponds to the first $n$ letters of ABBA. For instance, $E_4 = 0$, while $E_2$ is the expected number of keystrokes needed when the last two keys pressed were A and B, in that order.

If we are at the stage where the last two letters were AB, then there is a $\frac1{26}$ probability that the next letter will be B, and we have now gotten ABB. There is a $\frac1{26}$ probability that the next letter will be A, and then we will be back at A. Then we have a $\frac{24}{26}$ probability that it will be neither, and we're back where we started. Similarily for the other $E_n$s. This gives
$$
E_4 = 0\\
E_3 = \frac1{26}(1+E_4) + \frac{25}{26}(1+E_0)\\
E_2 = \frac1{26}(1+E_3) + \frac1{26}(1+E_1) + \frac{24}{26}(1+E_0)\\
E_1 = \frac1{26}(1+E_2) + \frac1{26}(1+E_1) + \frac{24}{26}(1+E_0)\\
E_0 = \frac1{26}(1+E_1) + \frac{25}{26}(1+E_0)
$$
Solving these five equations gives $E_0 = 456\,976 = 26^4$. So your rough approximation was actually correct.

Comment: There's a mistake in your line for $E_1$. The last term should have probability $\frac{24}{26}$, not $\frac{25}{26}$

Comment: @TeenPhilosopher You're right. Fortunately, that mistake did not make it into wolframalpha when I told it to solve these equations for me. The answer is still $E_0 = 26^4$.